# change container fluid class in resolution up than 1200

Tags: resolution

How can I change div class from `container-fluid` to `container` when resolution greater than 1200?
im working with bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the class names on html, you can use Jquery. Like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var container = $('.container');
    var containerFluid = $('.container-fluid');
    if(windowWidth < 600){
        containerFluid.removeClass('container-fluid').addClass('container');
    }else if (windowWidth > 600){
       container.removeClass('container').addClass('container-fluid');
    }
});
```

Here is [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tallrye/7m0ksp3d/)

As you can see, according to window size, class changes on html.